# How to process only delta files in aws datapipeline and EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, emr, amazon-data-pipeline

How to process only new files using AWS data pipeline and EMR? I may get different number of files in my source directory. I want to process them using AWS data pipeline and EMR as one file after another file. I'm not sure how pre condition "exists" or "Shell Command activity" can solve this issue. Please suggest a way to process a delta list of files by adding EMR steps or creating EMR clusters for each file.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is usually done in datapipeline is to use schedule expressions when referring to the source directory.   For example,

if your pipeine is scheduled to run hourly and you specify "s3://bucket/#{format(minusMinutes(@scheduledStartTime,60),'YYYY-MM-dd hh')}"

as the input directory,  datapipeline will resolve that to "s3://bucket/2016-10-23-16" when its running at hour 17.  So the job will only read data corresponding to hour 16.  If you can structure your input to produce data in this manner, this can be used.  See  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-expressions.html for more examples of expressions.

Unfortunately,  there is no built-n support "get data since last processed".